Вывод числа с плавающей точкой до определённого знака после запятой без округления
j=float(0.15+0.005*62)
print(j)#0.45999999999999996 
number = 3.1415926535

formatted_number = f"{j:.5f}" 
print(formatted_number) #выводит 46.00000
formatted_number = f"{number:.5f}" 
print(formatted_number) #выводит 3.14159

Мне нужно оставить в переменной j=0.45999999999999996 5 знаков после запятой без округления, но все время округляется. Причем с одной переменной работает корректно, с другой нет. Как решить проблему? Мне обязательно нужно не просто вывести число, но и записать его значение.

У вас с обеими переменными происходит округление, просто во втором случае это совпадает с тем результатом, который вы хотите. Округление для чисел меньше 5 происходит вниз, поэтому так.
Для вывода нужного числа знаков проще всего воспользоваться таким способом:
print(j - j % 1e-5)
# 0.45999

Просто отбрасываем из числа остаток от деления его на 0.00001.
Если вдруг этот метод вам не подойдёт по каким-то причинам, то можно подсмотреть и другие методы на английском СО.
P.S. Насчёт взятия остатка от деления на 0.00001 смотрим Деление с остатком, формула для получения остатка:
q = [a/b]
r = a - b*q

Подставим наши значения:
q = [0.45999999999999996 / 0.00001] = [0.45999999999999996 * 100000] = [45999.999999999996] = 45999
r = 0.45999999999999996 - 0.00001 * 45999 = 0.45999999999999996 - 0.45999 = 0.00000999999999996

Легко видеть, что этот остаток от деления - это как-раз то, что нам нужно вычесть из исходного числа, чтобы получить 0.45999:
0.45999999999999996 - 0.45999 = 0.00000999999999996
0.45999 = 0.45999999999999996 - 0.00000999999999996


а можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, как так взяли остаток, просто 0.4599999996 % 0.00001 это же нужно поделить на число и взять в итоге остаток от деления, но тут так как десятичная дробь, то умножаем 0.4599999996 * 100000 = 45999.99996 и как в итоге взять остаток от этого числа?

@Sashkinzz Добавил ссылку на Википедию и подсчёт на ваших числах по формулам оттуда )

Т.е. фактически от 45999.99996 целая часть берётся обычным образом - отбрасыванием того, что после запятой. А вот дальше при нахождении собственно остатка получается, что мы обратно на 0.00001 эту целую часть умножаем по формуле, прежде чем вычесть из исходного числа.

спасибо большое!

В качестве идеи:
s = str(340.0098765678)
print(s[:s.find(".") + 6])

Выводит на экран: 340.00987
